# Visual Studio 2013 - Add Item > Report option missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, report, rdlc

I want to create **RDLC** file in my C# project. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252067.aspx) But I'm not getting Reporting item templates (**Report** or **Report Wizard**).
I've got VS2013 Professional Edition so I assume it should have been there.

I've also installed SQL Server Data Tools for VS2013 and I'm able to create New Report Server Project and add a report there. But that's RDL file, that's not what I'm looking for.

I've tried `devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates` with no luck.

I'm not able to find these item templates online either (not sure if my company firewall is blocking anything).

Does anyone know what could be the reason for missing item templates (**Report** or **Report Wizard**) and how can I get those added in my current project?

Comment: Someone upvoted this question today, 3 yrs after I asked it, making it 8 upvotes. Strange thing is no one has upvoted the answer yet :-| . I wonder if that answer is helping anyone or not :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing VS 2013 Update 4 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44916) I'm able to see Reporting item templates.

Please note: I had installed Report Viewer Runtime and Redistributable package as suggested by @Scott before installing Update 4. That time Reporting item templates were not available.
Now I'm not sure if Update 4 in itself is sufficient for item templates or you need Update 4 + Report Viewer runtime/redistributable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the Microsoft Report Viewer Runtime/Redistribution?  These install the report viewer controls.

[Microsoft Report Viewer Runtime 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35747)

[Microsoft Report Viewer 2010 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6442)